# Creating a placeholder-like function that is not removed in input html

Tags: javascript, html

Placeholders are nice. It made our lives easier when creating user-friendly input components.

What I'm trying to do now is to create placeholder like text in my input that is not removed when text is entered.

Example) When I type enter my email address, @gmail.com will appear grayed out after the text I entered. However, it's like a placeholder, so you are not able to select/drag or change the value

j`@gmail.com` 
ja`@gmail.com`
jay`@gmail.com`

Highlighted area is grayed out and unclickable inside the input box

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: Check out the jQuery mask plugin. Maybe this could solve your problem.
https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer because I can't figure out how to get the color of the "placeholder" text to always be gray while the entered text is black, but maybe this can be the beginning of an answer if someone else can push it the rest of the way over the goalpost. I used two textboxes stacked on top of one another. The top one has opacity zero and is the one you are actually entering text into. The bottom one takes the value from the top one and adds the placeholder text to it.

https://jsfiddle.net/c4L76tzu/14/

HTML

```
<input id="secret" type="text" size="15" />
<input id="open" type="text" size="15" value="@gmail.com"/>
```

CSS

```
#secret {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
#open {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("secret").oninput = function() {BleedThru()};
function BleedThru() {
  var secret = document.getElementById("secret");
  var open = document.getElementById("open");
  open.value = secret.value + "@gmail.com";
  console.log(open.value);
}
```